# How to set Flask static folder path to ionic production build folder "www" in python flask , Ionic 5?

Tags: python, angular, flask, ionic4, flask-restful

How to set Flask static folder path to ionic production build folder "www" in python flask , Ionic 5?

I want to set flask static folder to ionic production build folder "www", without creating any static_folder or template_folder separately.
So that we can run our application in one server .

Answer (score 0):

I changed my static folder by just mention the name while instantiating the app.

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='my_folder')
```

After this, for confirmation, I just run this command.

```
print(url_for('static', filename='hi.txt'))
```

I got this output like this `/my_folder/hi.txt`.

Note:  Make sure that, you app user have the right permission for `www` folder.